# Is it safe to use email from OAuth for authentication?

Tags: oauth, oauth2, openid-connect

I am implementing OAuth (more specifically "Sign in with Google") for a website that has been using only email and password for years.

Now the guide that I'm reading suggests to read the `uid` in the OAuth callback. However the existing users, that have signed up with other methods, don't have that information in the database. Basically they would get a new, separate account.

If I could identify the users using their email, however, I could provide a better flow: the users would be recognized immediately.

The email addresses on my website are verified through email confirmation.

Is it safe to rely on the email returned by identity providers like Google? Or I should rely only on the "provider / uid" for authentication?

Answer (score 1):

In general, you need to store a unique ID for each user when using external sign-on.  Consider the following scenario:

1. User A signs up with example.com for the email `user@example.com`.
2. User A creates an account on your site using external SSO.  You link the account.
3. User A deletes their account.
4. User B signs up with the email `user@example.com`.

User B now has access to all of User A's data, which is very bad (and may additionally expose you to legal liability depending on the jurisdiction).  Note that had User A signed up with an email and password, User B wouldn't have had the password and therefore couldn't have logged in.  In case you think email reuse is not a problem, I assure you that it does indeed happen at some Fortune 500 companies.

What many sites do is to refuse the login with SSO if there's already an existing account with that email address, forcing them to use the existing credentials, and then once they're logged in, allow them to link the two accounts.  That is a secure way to solve the problem and still lets people take advantage of the SSO in the future if they prefer.

Answer (score 1):

[OAuth is not meant to be used for authentication](https://oauth.net/articles/authentication/). You should use a protocol that is meant for authentication, like OpenID Connect (which uses OAuth for *part* of the protocol).

OAuth's vanilla use case is to obtain a token to authorize your app to perform actions on behalf of the user, against some other service. For example, you'd get an OAuth token for the user's Google account, in order to access specific Google APIs on their behalf from your app.